# SetTimeout fadeOut закрытие всплывающих подсказок по очереди

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть всплывающие подсказки, закрывающиеся по таймеру:

```
$(".add_to_cart_small_red_ico").click(function () {
   $(this).next(".effect").show("fade", {}, 300);
   setTimeout(function() {
     $(".effect").fadeOut(500);}, 5000);
});
```

Всплывающие окна по окончанию таймера закрываются все одновременно, подскажите пожалуйста, чего не хватает, что бы подсказки закрывались по очереди?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы скрываете все элементы с классом effect, зачем ?

как я понимаю кейс такой - кликаем по 10 элементам add_to_cart_small_red_ico, и как только закрывается первый закрываются  и  остальные. это естественно. т.к. вы говорите - "закрыть их все".

чтобы закрывать только элемент после того который кликали делайте так:

```
$(".add_to_cart_small_red_ico").click(function () {
   var $el=$(this).next(".effect"); //в $el теперь один элемент, в ...
   $el.show("fade", {}, 300);
   setTimeout(function() {
     $el.fadeOut(500);}, 5000); //callback функции setTimeout используем его-же
});
```

для самообразования вам нужно понять когда использовать селекторы а когда результаты селекторов, вообще секрет очень простой - в своих функциях callback не надо использовать глобальных  селекторов.

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @xmocartx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

ещё вам хорошо бы  обработать второе нажатие на элемент (закрыть например подсказку или наоборот "продолжить действие") для этого  проще всего подвесить к элементу `$el.data(timeout_id)` и убирать его при срабатывании таймаута, а при клике проверять наличие этого значения, сбрасывать таймаут и производить соответвующее действие

Comment: Буду разбираться) Еще раз спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, [можно сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VVLuG/). Т.е. мы для каждого последующего элемента увеличиваем интервал до скрытия.

```
$(".add_to_cart_small_red_ico").click(function () {
    $('.effect').each(function(i,el){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(el).fadeOut();
        },500 * i);
    });
});
```

Comment: как я  понял, задача немного другая :)